# npm install [module] works when inside the directory of ssh key but will not work in another directory. Windows powershell

Tags: powershell, npm, ssh, npm-install

Very strange to me.  When I am in C:\Users\xxxx\Project and run "npm install [module]" I get a github error "git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey)."

If I run the command (from the same path) ssh -T git@github.com I get a success message of
"Hi user!  You've been authenticated..."

If I go to the directory C:\Users\xxxx.ssh and run "npm install [module]" everything seems to work fine.

I have tried running the command "ssh-add ...ssh\id_ed25519" which prompts for a pass phrase and outputs a success message.

This is all on Windows PowerShell.

Thank you for looking.

I have tried adding my ssh private key to the agent, I verified it is setup in Github and it appears I am able to authenticate.  I can install modules from inside the .ssh directory and github authenticates, but it does not authenticate if I try to run the command from seemingly any other directory.